# Can't use GetUserInfo for Group Edition organizations (SOAP Partner API) anymore

Tags: soap-api, group-edition, partner-wsdl

I use the `GetUserInfo` service from the SOAP Partner API, through a call very similar **[1]** to: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/PartnerGetUserInfo.

This call works perfectly for all types of organizations, including Group and Professional, if we use version 11.0 or below of the API. But, with version 12.0 or above (I tried up to version 29.0), it doesn't work with Group Edition organizations (I tested with a free trial organization **[2]** created from [this page](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/freetrial-sales-ge.jsp)).

In this case, Salesforce answers with a faultcode `sf:API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG`

This looks like a bug as we haven't seen any documentation about this difference between Group and Professional Edition.

Does someone know if it's a bug or an (undocumented?) limitation?

**[1]** In my call, I use a [Client ID](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_header_calloptions.htm) but it does not seem to make the difference: if I remove it, it still works with Pro Edition and it still doesn't work with Group Edition.

**[2]** I didn't use a test org from [Partner Portal](http://www.salesforce.com/partners/overview/) because this type of organization does not share the same API limits as real organizations. As a matter of fact, my call *does* work with a Group Edition organization created with the Partner Portal.